# Magento Connect error: The 'community' channel is not installed

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I have packaged a extension when i try to install it form connect manager on my localhost... i am getting this error

```
CONNECT ERROR: The 'community' channel is not installed. Please use the MAGE shell script to install the 'community' channel.
```

I have read some where that The official solution to this is to run the Magento setup-command over SSH:

```
chmod 755 mage
./mage mage-setup
```

But i am confused how i use SSH on localhost on windows platform

Please Suggest whats the solution for this Magento connect error

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

Right command is (note the final dot)

```
./mage mage-setup .
```

Comment: Does not work:

Running initial setup...
Success
Success
Error: 
channel-add: Channel 'community' already exist!

Comment: it meas `'community' already exist!` so you don't need to do it. Is it your error the same in the above question: `CONNECT ERROR: The 'community' channel is not installed. ... ` ? If no, please open another question

Comment: You are right, I screwed up. In my extension config I set the entire URL as the channel, not just "community"

Answer (score 1):

Just save the settings in Magento Connect manager (see /downloader/ route in your Magento instance - `http://yoursite.com/downloader/`). Works for me on version 1.5.1.0.

Comment: Doesn't work for me so the 'just save the settings' should be removed as a solution. I would say something like 'For me, doing this and that worked'

Answer (score 0):

http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2011/05/15/magento-15-ee-110-windows-command-line-batch-update-script-magebat

Has a batch file that may offer some help.

I would recommend you look into [Virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization) with a Linux installation as Magento is really geared more for Linux environments than WAMP stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Note:

Please check if when creating the package extension file what value you entered in `channel` column under `Package Info` Section.

Solution:  The `channel` value must be `community`.

You can check this value in `var/connect/your_package.tgz/package.xml`file.

This should look like:

```
<channel>community</channel>
```

Thanks